# Android - Global Variables and TextView objects

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, textview, global-variables

I'm currently teaching myself Android programming, so please explain your answers in a way that a beginner could understand.

I'm trying to edit the text in a TextView object using public static String objects from other screens/activities.
There are two public static string objects, called crew_id and orderType respectively (both are initialized as empty strings). There is a TextView object in an Activity called NewOrderActivity with the id "crew_id_and_ordertype".

My code for NewOrderActivity.class is currently this:

The code for the button to start the NewOrderActivity is:

```
public void goToNewOrder(View view)
{
    final EditText edit =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); //gets the string from the EditText object
    crew_id = edit.getText().toString();
    Intent k = new Intent(CrewIDActivity.this, NewOrderActivity.class);
    startActivity(k);
}
```

The code for NewOrderActivity is:

```
public class NewOrderActivity
extends Activity{
TextView info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.crew_id_and_ordertype);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_order);
    info.setText("Crew ID: " + CrewIDActivity.crew_id + "/n /n" + OrderingActivity.orderType);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.new_order, menu);
    return true;
}
```

When I try to go to from the previous activity to NewOrderActivity, the app stops working.
What am I doing wrong? Is it a problem with how I'm trying to edit the TextView object, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot initialize components unless the view is set. TextView info line of code should be placed after `setContentView`

```
public class NewOrderActivity
extends Activity{
TextView info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.crew_id_and_ordertype);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_order);
    info.setText("Crew ID: " + CrewIDActivity.crew_id + "/n /n" + OrderingActivity.orderType);
}
```

Change it to this way:

```
public class NewOrderActivity
extends Activity{


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_order);
TextView info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.crew_id_and_ordertype);
    info.setText("Crew ID: " + CrewIDActivity.crew_id + "/n /n" + OrderingActivity.orderType);
}
```

Comment: Cool, Glad I could help you. Please vote up my answer and encourage newbies like me.